# Copying variable files from the same path in different folders

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to copy the files (with the same extensions but varying file names) from every user's signatures folder, into a dump folder, using batch.

For example;

I have 3 users' roaming profiles on my C: drive, the usernames are initials, followed by a tag which they all have (initials_1);

```
C:\Users\abc_1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\test.htm
         def_1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\example.htm
         ghi_1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Signature.htm
```

I want to be able to copy the 3 .htm files into my new folder `C:\Users\Admin\Signatures`

In this case the usernames are initials and there are around 100 different users so i'm trying to avoid having to do it manually.

Please let me know if this would be possible using batch or if I would have to use Vbs?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have multiple directories from which to copy, how do you propose to record them all in the one destination directory?

Comment: I don't, I just want to dump all the .htm files in this one destination directory

Comment: @RickyTabletop, what Magoo is trying to say is what do you want to do when two profiles have the same file name.

Comment: Although I'm confident none of them will have the same name, if this did occur surely I would be able to input Y/N to the overwrite prompt, then make a note of those with duplicate file names and go through those manually?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more usefull to copy them as `username_filename.htm`?

Comment: It would - I wasn't aware this was possible.. would you be kind enough to suggest which command would be best suited to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%G in ("C:\Users\*") DO (
    if exist "%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures" (
        set "name=%%~nxG"
        if not "x!name:_1=!"=="x!name!" (
            copy "%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm" "C:\Users\Admin\Signatures\!name!_*.htm"
        )
    )
)
```

The line `FOR /D %%G in ("C:\Users\*") DO (...)` means that code inside the parenthesis gets executed for every (non-recursive, else use `/D /R`) directory inside the C:\Users directory. The full path of the subdirectory gets stored in %%G, for instance `C:\Users\abc_1`.

`if exist "%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures" (...)` means the code inside those parenthesis only gets executed if the %%G directory contains a Signatures folder.

`set "name=%%~nxG"` stores the name and extension (if your directory name contains a `.`) of the directory in %%G inside the name variable, so only `abc_1`, without the `C:\Users\` in front of it.

`if not "x!name:_1=!"=="x!name!" (...)` checks if the name contains _1 by comparing the name with `_1` removed with the name itself. You need `!` here instead of `%` because your inside parenthesis, that's why `DelayedExpansion` is enabled. For more information about delayed expansion, read [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Outside of a code block this would work like `%variableName:StringToFind=StringToReplaceItWith%`

The copy simply copies all `.htm` files from the signatures directory of each user to the admin's signatures directory, but with `!name!` (which contains for example `abc_1`) prepended to it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your help, just for future reference/help in learning, what does the above code do in a literal sense? I.e. 'for folders in this path ending in _1 perform this...' Thanks again.

Comment: @RickyTabletop added an explanation

Comment: @RickyTabletop The same to you!